# ADB crash constantly

Tags: android, crash, adb

When i'm using Android Studio for hours (6-7) after a while the ADB becomes unstable. I mean it crashes random over and over again. It's 
frustrating that my Nexus 7 is disconnected every time adb crash.

It occurs every time when i'm using for hours. I tried with

- other cable
- plug into other USB ports
- restart Android Studio
- `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server` // fails

Finally it always become unusable like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2oxB.gif

As much as I can figure out only a system restart solves the problem but I think this isn't the proper solution for the problem.

Anyone suffers the same problem? How can I solve this without system restart?

Comment: I also have this problem when I am using an external device for testing. Typically I unplug the phone and plug it back in and ADB will become responsive again.

Comment: Thank you @mattfred, i tried you suggestion. It's kinda weird..
First, i unplug, then plug in, finally start the adb but it crashes immediately.
Then i unplug, start the adb, then plug in. This time it worked for 10 minutes then crashes on its own. Android Studio was not open, and i wasn't using my tablet.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Make sure to switch between USB 3.0 and USB 2.0.

Source: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12491/adb-constantly-disconnects-shows-device-offline

Comment: Thank you @micoror1. My laptop have three USB port, two of them have this problem (one of them surely USB 2.0). I will try the third one as soon as I can but it really bothering me.