# adb crashes constantly on AVD

Tags: android, adb, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

My **adb** crashes constantly (every second) whenever i start **avd** from **andorid studio**. 
I have tried all posts here in stackOverflow, with no luck :(

Here is the log from ***windows event viewer*** so far:

**Information:**

```
Fault bucket 108798948236, type 1
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: adb.exe
P2: 0.0.0.0
P3: 34f534d5
P4: StackHash_623e
P5: 10.0.10240.17184
P6: 580ee54f
P7: c0000374
P8: PCH_1C_FROM_ntdll+0x000690BC
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_adb.exe_8a5ee84daf5aa5ad47be8cc7d8df3aa8ddf62e2f_06e977f2_23d93e60

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 9cc143bb-d928-4a2d-8f0e-cb9fed4a612e
Report Status: 0
Hashed bucket: 21161e0a43fdbfee778bc366fd70ee30
```

**Error**

```
Faulting application name: adb.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x34f534d5
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.10240.17184, time stamp: 0x580ee54f
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x000d62ac
Faulting process id: 0x3bb8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3bf6c2b6dedcd
Faulting application path: C:\Users\jake\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 2fdcbdc9-fefc-457e-b6bc-6b28d4a812b8
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278189/adb-crash-constantly

Comment: already tried that @ShaluTD

Comment: Are you sure adb is correctly installed? `version: 0.0.0.0` sounds very strange to me. What does it say if you type `adb --version` in the console?

Comment: adb is installed correctly. i have checked it on console.

Comment: it show this,
`Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
Version 0.0.1-4500957`

Comment: what is your CPU brand ? is it amd or intel ?

Comment: @BasilBattikhi its intel Xeon

Comment: have you checked the virtualization technology is enabled in bios ?

Comment: @BasilBattikhi its enabled.

Comment: does the emulator run without the appplication ?

Comment: i suggest to redownload-upgrade the SDK platform

Comment: emulator runs, but it steals focus whenever `adb` crashes.

Comment: @BasilBattikhi what is the problem in your opinion?

Comment: i think there are some problem with platform-tools itself, have you to created older or newer emulator ?

Comment: yes, at least ten times

Comment: In my case adb crashes as soon as it disconnects from the adb server. For example: `adb getprop` will list all the properties, and then the crash will occur. Is this also the case with you?
Also: you can try downgrading to version 1.0.36. It's the highest version that doesn't crash in my case, but it's too old for my purposes :(.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone expiriencing this problem, please check if Forefronte TMG Client is installed on your system. It seems that it's incompatible with some ADB commands. On Windows 7 you could run ADB under compatibliti mode with Windows Server 2003 to avoid app crash with Forefront TMG Client installed.

Bug related to this issue that I posted at google issuetracker was fixed yesterday.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130786169 so ADB since version 1.0.41 should work OK.